# How to unit test on Customer Transformer implementation of Solr

Tags: unit-testing, solr, transformer-model

How can I do unit test on Customer Transformer implementation of Solr ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A starting point would be to check the Transformers test @ http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_3/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/test/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/ and emulate them

For unit testing you can probably do it standalone by including the jars, or include the tests within the solr source code and run the complete test suite.